# SQL WHERE in IIF with User Input

Tags: sql, ms-access, user-input, iif

I'd like to combine separate queries that prompt for user input into a single query.

Q1 Prompts User to enter 9 digit ITEM (PN):

```
SELECT 
STUFF,
MORE_STUFF
FROM dbo_X
WHERE (RIGHT(dbo_X.ITEM, 9)=[PN:])
ORDER BY dbo_X.COMPONENT
```

Q2 Prompts User to enter some portion of ItemDesc (Description):

```
SELECT 
STUFF,
MORE_STUFF
FROM dbo_X
WHERE dbo_x.ItemDesc LIKE '*'&[Description:]&'*'
ORDER BY dbo_X.COMPONENT
```

My thinking is to use IIf to execute a single WHERE statement based upon user input:

```
SELECT 
STUFF,
MORE_STUFF
FROM dbo_X
IIf ([Description{D}PartNumber{P}:]='D',
    WHERE dbo_X.ItemDesc LIKE '*'&[Desc:]&'*',
    WHERE (RIGHT(dbo_X.ITEM, 9)=[PN:]))
ORDER BY dbo_X.COMPONENT
```

Not currently working and not sure if I have syntax issues or am attempting to use IIf/When improperly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adjusting your workflow and use a dedicated user interface such as MS Access' forms and not rely on query parameter pop-ups which in best design is not the standard way of receiving values of named parameters.

1. Create a form of three text boxes for *Description(D), PartNumber(P)*, *Desc:*, and *PIN:* values which can be validated for character length conditionally linked (locked/not visible) by first box.
2. Save both queries pointing to form controls:

   ```
   SELECT 
   STUFF,
   MORE_STUFF
   FROM dbo_X
   WHERE (RIGHT(dbo_X.ITEM, 9)=Forms!myform![PN:])
   ORDER BY dbo_X.COMPONENT

   SELECT 
   STUFF,
   MORE_STUFF
   FROM dbo_X        
   WHERE dbo_x.ItemDesc LIKE '*'& Forms!myform![Description:] &'*'
   ORDER BY dbo_X.COMPONENT
   ```
3. On same new form, place a command button to output queries and have that button via VBA or macro to call the corresponding query depending on *Description(D), PartNumber(P)*. And with this approach, no pop-ups will occur as all parameters are satisfied on form.

   ```
   If Forms!myform![Description(D), PartNumber(P)] = 'D' Then
       DoCmd.OpenQuery "DescriptionQuery"
   Else
       DoCmd.OpenQuery "PinQuery"
   End If
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`iif()` is an expression, not a clause.  So, you cannot use it that way.

On the other hand, you can do:

```
SELECT STUFF, MORE_STUFF
FROM dbo_X
WHERE ([Description{D}PartNumber{P}:] = 'D' AND dbo_X.ItemDesc LIKE '*'&[Desc:]&'*') OR
      ([Description{D}PartNumber{P}:] <> 'D' AND RIGHT(dbo_X.ITEM, 9) = [PN:]))
ORDER BY dbo_X.COMPONENT;
```

Oh, and that didn't even require `iif()`.

By the way, the expression is a wee bit more complicated if `[Description{D}PartNumber{P}:]` could have a `NULL` value (just use the `nz()` function).

Comment: Tried that but it still prompts for all 3 inputs. Would like to prompt for only 1 of Desc or PN based upon the first input 'D' or 'P'. (Note: remove 2nd comma after [PN])

Comment: Regardless of logic, to run query the Access engine needs to know the values of all named parameters, hence all three prompts.

Comment: @cixelsyd . . . Parfait is correct.  MS Access is prompting for the values during the compilation phase of the query, not the execution phase.